# Ethereum contract not allowing or transfering

Tags: contract-development, tokens

I have published my Ethereum contract along with the source code to the test network `ROPSTEN` here:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x4eada3f012a0dbdeff59a8ac62be07dfff71c90f#readContract

However, I am confused why only the `approve` and `balanceOf` functions work. All of the other functions return `false` or `0` when I try to run them using another test address: `0x458D19B5071b4C7B265793394c80e75BaECb5091`. As you can see by the source code, I have a pretty straight-forward `ERC 20` implementation... could it really be because my `Allowed` variable is capitalized instead of lower case? That is the only unique thing from the standard implementation that I found... is that the issue or am I missing something else?

Comment: What functions have you tried to call and with what parameters? Things seem to be working okay for me... I just called `balanceOf` with the address `0xd52193f518619aaa043f2a112717c7a2fd1e35e9` (the current `OwnerAddress`), and it returned `18000000`. (BTW, I think this is a mistake... you multiplied 1000000 by `Decimals`, but you probably meant to multiply by 10 to the power of `Decimals`.)

Comment: You are right about `balanceOf`, question updated, and yes, that was supposed to be a `**` of instead of a `*`, which I already fixed in my local source code... but when I try to test to see how much was `allowed(0xd52193f518619aaa043f2a112717c7a2fd1e35e9, 0x458D19B5071b4C7B265793394c80e75BaECb5091)` even after I `approve(0x458D19B5071b4C7B265793394c80e75BaECb5091, 1000)` (I tried various amounts), it always shows 0, nor does it let me `transfer` any

Comment: I don't see any inbound transactions to the contract. I suspect you're trying things out in the "Read Smart Contract" tab, but nothing you do there will have any permanent effect. To actually mutate state in the contract, you need to send a transaction.

Comment: Oh, I see. Can you recommend a way to do that? I tried adding the contract to my `MetaMask`, but it shows that I have 0.000 amount of that contract there... I'm sorry if this is all `newb` stuff to you but that's because I am pretty new to this. BTW, if you answer the question with your last comment, especially if you answer this comment, I will give you credit for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying from my comment:

I don't see any inbound transactions to the contract. I suspect you're trying things out in the "Read Smart Contract" tab, but nothing you do there will have any permanent effect. To actually mutate state in the contract, you need to send a transaction.

[Remix](http://remix.ethereum.org/) + [MetaMask](https://metamask.io) is a good option for trying out the functions in your smart contract. Make sure you're using the same account in MetaMask as you used to initially deploy the contract.